How to get AD group members from a group with members from multiple domains
I want to get member list by using Get-ADGroupMember -Identity targetgroup.
The target group has members which is from domain A and domain B.
This is image
Target group members
member1 (domain A)
member2 (domain A)
member3 (domain A)
member4 (domain B)
In this situation, an error occurred.
CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (targetgroup:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8224,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
I don’t need to get member list from domain B.
Please tell me how to fix the error and get the member who is a member of domain A.
I added -Server parameter and tried this command.
Get-ADGroupMembers -Identity targetgroup -Server DomainControllerfromdomainA
(DomainControllerfromdomainA is a server name)
But the parameter wasn’t recognized  and error occurred.

Please ask a new question, you're using the code provided in my answer in your latest edit. That belongs in a new question. Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Try using the filter, this shouldn't try to resolve membership for identities not in your Domain (which I assume is Domain A):
$dn = (Get-ADGroup -Identity targetgroup).DistinguishedName
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(memberOf=$dn)"


Thank you so much for your help. I have successfully get members from domain A only.　　
However, I get an error when I merge into the overall script.　　
Could you please tell me how to fix.　　
The error is "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'.

@おもこ you should create a new question. This answer is for the question being asked.
